# How do I make IE9 emulate IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I used:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

in the header to force IE8 to emulate IE7. Will it do the same thing for IE9? I don't have IE9 and I'm running XP so can't install it to find out.

If anyone with IE9 can test this page for me, I'd greatly appreciate it! It's a mootools slideshow and works with every browser I've tried it on including IE8. Arrows should change the photo, the thumbnails should scroll back and forth.

http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/test

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this should work.  See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx) for exhaustive info on IE compatibility modes.  I tested your link on IE9 running under Windows 7 and it looked/worked OK for me.

Comment: Cool, thank you Brian. I went down to the computer store where they had Windows 7 and IE9 running and I tried a page with and without that meta tag. The page flat-out won't work without the compatibility mode code. Works (pretty much, but sometimes the thumbnails are messed up) in compatibility mode.