# Tumblr site divs not looking right in ie8 or 9 but right in ie7. Fix?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9, css-float

Here is the site I am referring to (the css is built in)
freebirdbooks.com/tagged/about

I am having a problem getting my site to preview correctly in ie8 and ie9 only. It looks fine in any other browser. I should mention I am coding the HTML and CSS myself, but using Tumblr as the content management system for a client. (This is until I can learn how to code my own back end for clients which I know is ideal.)

This site looks fine in most browsers. But in ie8 and ie9 only, my container and sidebar divs "underlap." I uploaded some preview images to my hosting site for you because since I am a new user they won't let me.

Is there any way to fix this? This site has been very helpful in the past, and I thank anyone who can help in advance.

http://images.freebirdbooks.com/rightway.jpg
http://images.freebirdbooks.com/uglyway.jpg

Leah

Comment: You could look into ie7 emulating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397568/how-do-i-make-ie9-emulate-ie7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works for me on IE8 (I don't have IE 9):

Add

```
#sidebar{clear:both;}
```

and remove

```
#wrapper #sidebar{min-height:1100px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to close all of your anchor tags inside the headerimage div.

Comment: Michael thank you for pointing out the closing of the anchor tags. Sometimes looking at code makes my eyes blurry! I appreciate that. Best, Leah

Comment: If you use a program like Netbeans it will show you the places in your code that may have any issues. Dreamweaver has something built into it as well, but Netbeans is much better (and free, but a resource hog). Many like to code in Notepad++, but I'm not sure if that has a plugin that would work. I personally find this feature to be a life saver, especially when I have to work/fix code that somebody else originally wrote.